# mysql query how to show each day's total cash sale for the current week

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query which shows the each day's total cash sale for the current week.

```
SELECT  
  sum(Price) as totalprice,
  WEEKDAY(CreatedOn) as dayno,
  DATE(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
  AgentID  
FROM records
WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN (CURDATE()-WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(CreatedOn)
```

When I run the query it looks like this:

[image]

There are records on 30th November(today's date). So,

day 0 (Monday) no cash sale

day 1 (Tuesday) $5049

day 2 (Wednsday) $99

Nothing is displayed for day 3 (Thursday/today). I cannot figure out the reason there are definitely record in the database but cannot get them to be displayed. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURDATE() is today's date but at 00:00:00+0000000

"push up" the higher date by 1 day and avoid using between for date/time ranges:

```
WHERE CreatedOn >= date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) 
AND CreatedOn < date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)


select date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) 
     , date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. would it help if CreatedOn column type was timestamp?

Comment: *"Would it help if CreatedOn column type was timestamp?"* well I'm hoping it isn't a string. Personally I believe in accuracy, so I would use a timestamp. but that does mean you need to use date/time ranges even for a single day of data.

Comment: both spencer7593 and I have offered solutions that do not use "between" and that is because "**between sucks for date ranges**" as it includes both the earlier and the later date into the range. So it is far easier to just use 2 simple predicates instead. It's a a negligible increase in code length that gains far greater accuracy.

Comment: This follows the "best practice" pattern for datetime range conditions ... `dt >= start and dt < end`.  (The equality condition should be on one side or the other, not both. +10.  (This pattern is so frequent, and usable for date, datetime, timestamp, decimal, float, double and even character datataypes, the ANSI SQL standard should recommend (IMO) a `BETWEEN_GE_LT` operator.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in the query currently specifies on or before midnight today, so any rows for today after midnight are going to be excluded.

I think you are intending to specify CreatedOn before midnight of the following day.

I also suggest you don't subtract an integer value from a date/datetime, and instead use the INTERVAL syntax

```
WHERE CreatedOn >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
  AND CreatedOn <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

To test those expressions before we include them in a query, we can run a SELECT statement:

```
 SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
      , CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

and verify that those expressions are returning what we expect, the values we want to use. For testing, we can replace CURDATE() with a date value to test the return for days other than today.

Comment: hi! It seems complex. If I have datetime format type for the CreatedOn column would it be easier?

Comment: The "datetime in range" pattern demonstrated here isn't really that complex... it's the standard pattern `t.dt >= start and t.dt < end`. (Could it be less complex? Maybe. But this pattern isn't very complicated. And it *works* for date and datetime, with fractional seconds. Normally, we usually do *not* want a `datetime` value to fall into two separate ranges when it's on a boundary. I stay with what has been demonstrated and proven to work accurately.